# Google chrome issue in JQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have created custom Date range picker using Jquery UI.

It works perfectly in other browser but in Google it not works properly.

See below snap.

The red round should be empty, but it gets some text, maybe because of loops but I can't figure it out.

[image]

My js code.

```
 $(function () {

        from = $("#from").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            minDate: +7, //THIS IS FIRST PLACE
            autoclose: false,
            beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
                $("#ui-datepicker-div td").off();

                $(document).on("mouseenter", "#ui-datepicker-div td", function (e) {
                    $(this).parent().addClass("finalRow");
                    $(".finalRow").parents('.ui-datepicker-group-last').parent().find('.ui-datepicker-group-first').find('tr').last().addClass("finalRowRangeOtherTable");
                    $(".finalRow").prevAll().find("td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)").removeClass("highlight");
                    $(this).prevAll("td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)").removeClass("highlight");
                });
            },
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var d = date.getTime();
                if ($("#to").datepicker("getDate") && d == $("#to").datepicker("getDate").getTime()) { 
                    return [true, 'ui-red', ''];
                }

                if ($("#from").datepicker("getDate") && $("#to").datepicker("getDate") && d < $("#to").datepicker("getDate").getTime() && d > $("#from").datepicker("getDate").getTime()) {
                    return [true, 'ui-state-highlight', ''];
                } else {
                    return [true, ''];
                }
            },
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                var selectedDate = $("#from").datepicker("getDate");
                if (selectedDate != null) {
                    $('#to').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate).datepicker('refresh'); //THIS IS SECOND PLACE
                }
                $("#from").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "d MM, yy");
                $("#to").datepicker("show");
            }
        })

        to = $("#to").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            autoclose: false,
            beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
                $("#ui-datepicker-div td").off();

                $(document).on("mouseenter", "#ui-datepicker-div td", function (e) {

                    $(this).parent().addClass("finalRow");
                    $(".finalRow").parents('.ui-datepicker-group-last').parent().find('.ui-datepicker-group-first').find('tr').last().addClass("finalRowRangeOtherTable");
                    $(".finalRowRangeOtherTable").find("td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)").addClass("highlight");
                    $(".finalRowRangeOtherTable").prevAll().find("td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)").addClass("highlight");

                    $(".finalRow").prevAll().find("td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)").addClass("highlight");
                    $(this).prevAll("td:not(.ui-datepicker-unselectable)").addClass("highlight");
                });

                $(document).on("mouseleave", "#ui-datepicker-div td", function (e) {

                    $(this).parent().removeClass("finalRow");
                    $("#ui-datepicker-div td").removeClass("highlight");

                    $(".finalRowRange").removeClass("finalRowRange").find('.highlight').removeClass("highlight");
                    $(".finalRowRangeOtherTable").removeClass("finalRowRangeOtherTable").find('.highlight').removeClass("highlight");

                });
            },
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var d = date.getTime();
                if ($("#from").datepicker("getDate") && d == $("#from").datepicker("getDate").getTime()) {
                    return [true, 'ui-red', ''];
                }
                if ($("#from").datepicker("getDate") && $("#to").datepicker("getDate") && d < $("#to").datepicker("getDate").getTime() && d > $("#from").datepicker("getDate").getTime()) {
                    return [true, 'ui-state-highlight', ''];
                } else {
                    return [true, ''];
                }
            }
        })
        .on("change", function () {
            from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "d MM, yy");
        });
    });
```

> I don't think it's issue with css because it works perfectly on other browsers even in IE.

**I also found that it occurs when and when I assign minDate to any of datepicker, see my comments in js code, If I remove that lines, datepicker works fine, but as I am using Custom range datepicker, I will need those lines, can I use any other alternative?**

Here is fiddle. [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/2fLew33h/)

1. **Open fiddle in GOOGLE CHROME**
2. Choose 10 Oct as start date
3. Choose 23 Oct as End Date
4. Now, Open both of the datepicker one by one, and hover over dates and you will see extra date as I added in snap (above)..
5. I couldn't overwrite css of live link, so design looks little bit owkword..

Comment: Seems like a bug with chrome 61. before the chrome update, this worked fine. After, i'm seeing OP's problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had your own problem.

Chrome does not seem to correctly resolve the unicode character &#xa0.

So search &#xa0 in your jquery-ui*.js and replace with "".

I replaced only the specified occurence of the character (search "ui-datepicker-other-month" in that file) and it works.

Comment: it's working, thanks! but i still not understand this, what this "&#xa0" actually do? and what if I remove it from whole js file?

Comment: "&#xa0" is the Unicode of Non-breaking space. I think that You should be careful when remove from whole js file. You should read the piece of code where the character is used to know exactly why is used. This kind of approach is useful to prevent any exception.

Comment: While this answer does technically solve the issue, i'm pretty sure this should be patched on Chrome's end. I would not recommend updating the jquery ui datepicker code unless you absolutely had to in order to fix the issue until chrome can patch it.

Answer (score 4):

As noted by Zyren this appears to have been a bug introduced in Chrome 61.  It has been fixed in Chrome 62.